# Divs wont stack but overlap instead

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overlap

I need the right-column1 to move under the left when the screen runs out of room for both to sit side by side.
Ive tried different overflows and setting media queries to 100% for left and right columns when the browser/device cant fit both side by side but to no avail.
The right column just overlaps the left and doesnt want to budge.
Most examples like this used to work without any issue a few weeks ago i think maybe ive changed something not sure.

I have the same setup with left containing an image and right containing a link but isnt working either.

Am i missing someting in my code?

```
<div class="container1">

<div class="left-column1">

<p class="title">More Wallpapers</p>
<div id="wn">
    <div id="lyr1">
        <div id="inner1">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>  <!-- end wn div --></div>

<div class="right-column1"><div class="fb-facepile" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Techagesite.Free.Mobile.Wallpapers" data-action="like" data-width="200" data-height="64" data-max-rows="2" data-colorscheme="dark" data-size="medium" data-show-count="true"></div></div>

</div>  



.container1 {
width: 100%;

}
.left-column1 {
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
.right-column1 {
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: @rohanam http://jsfiddle.net/439UX/1/

Comment: I gave my image example as is simplier

Comment: .left-column1 cannot have width:50%.

Comment: How come? @kashif qureshi

Comment: whats currently happening is  your left div will always stay at 50% of the screen size no matter what the size of screen is. Your image on other hand is fixed width which will get overflowed when left div gets smaller than the size of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removing width: 50%; from .left-column1 will fix the porblem

Comment: It worked but now the content below it (<hr> and <p>) are wrapping into it

Comment: www.techagesite.com/wrap.png

Comment: It worked but now my google ad is on top of the container and its contents. This is the ad here: <br><div style=''><script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- responsive1 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2873697026320753"
     data-ad-slot="5631594854"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
     <script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>
</div>

Comment: The ad is above the container in the code btw. Any thoughts?

Comment: do you have an updated jsfiddel or an example? did you apply clear:both on the first tag after your right column? clear:both is css property which should clear all existing positioning. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/439UX/7/ the google ad isnt going to show up in a fiddle btw but the codes there.

Comment: i would add one extra div as <div style="clear:both;"></div> before you start a container code <div class="container1">. Other then that nothing looks wrong to me in my browser.

Comment: You dont see the google ad covering the images? Try refresh the page as it can display a rectangle sometimes not a square ad. So in between containers add an empty div with clear both?

Comment: Added the clear class div and fixed the ad covering but now lol the original issue of the images and links in the left and right divs is playing up. They arent sitting beside each other now they are stacked. Have a look http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work1112211.htm

Comment: remove  clear:both from .right-column2 css. .right-column2 {
clear:both
width:50%;
float: left;
} . it clears the floating on right columns.

Comment: Im a bit confused sorry. what do i do?

Comment: The clear both on the right column is what i put to fix the last issue

Answer (score 1):

This is because your image get bigger that your div.
Just add `max-width` to it & it will work fine.

```
.left-column1 img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/439UX/3/)

Comment: Its not working. Could it be because i have 2 sets of the same code each with a different image and link right after the other like this http://jsfiddle.net/439UX/5/ but they line up correct unlike this fiddle

Comment: Also in your fiddle the right column doesnt go underneath the left like i need it to

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it stack using media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.left-column1 {
    width:100%;
}
.right-column1 {
    width:100%;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J5Q4u/

Does something like this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Give the image a max-width and an auto height.
http://jsfiddle.net/439UX/6/

```
.container1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.left-column1 {
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}
.right-column1 {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.left-column1 img { 
  max-width:100%; height:auto; 
}
```

Adding a media query avoids awkwardly small text columns:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
.container1 > div { width:100%; }
}
```

Comment: Is that going to make the image resize on browser resize? @superuntitled